# Calling LUIS speech recognition service

Tags: c#, speech-recognition, azure-cognitive-services, azure-language-understanding

I'm trying to build simple app using LUIS service. I use project oxford version 1.0.0.6 SpeechRecognitionServiceFactory.CreateDataClientWithIntent to create a data client, but confused with it's interface. My understanding is that LUIS accepts only text queries, but above client only has method SendAudio which accepts only byte array (works perfectly with CRIS when sending audio files). So, should this method be used to for text query as well or is there some other way to make this call?

Comment: Are you trying to call LUIS or the Bing Speech Recognition service?

Comment: I'm trying to call LUIS

Comment: Why you are mentioning speech recognition then? Are you using LUIS in the context of a bot or just from an desktop/web application?

Comment: The idea is to send audio to CRIS get answer back and send to LUIS to get intents and entities. Isn't it how it is supposed to work?

Comment: Are u using C#?

Comment: Yes, it's c# app

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are missing things. One thing is to call `CRIS` (and watch out I think that you are using an outdated SDK, take a look at the new [one](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/Cognitive-Speech-STT-Windows) and also to [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/custom-speech-service/customspeech-how-to-topics/cognitive-services-custom-speech-use-endpoint)), and another thing is to call `LUIS`, which is another SDK (this [one](https://github.com/Microsoft/Cognitive-LUIS-Windows)).

Once you get the output of CRIS, you can just call the LUIS SDK to send the query text.

Comment: This is the sample I'm talking about. They create LUIS (when selected on the UI) client and then read audio file from HDD and send to LUIS using SendAudioHelper function. How can it work, is LUIS is supposed to (IMHO) understand only text inptus? What I'm missing?

Comment: Also, I can use http client to send query to LUIS after I've got response from CRIS and everything works. Just stuck with example above and do not understand how it could work in SDK example

Comment: I don't know to which sample you are referring. It's unclear what you are asking

Comment: Sorry, missed this part, here is it - "Cognitive-Speech-STT-Windows/blob/master/samples/SpeechRecognitionServiceExample/MainWindow.xaml.cs"

Comment: So basically you want to understand what the internal code is doing? I would guess that it basically does the same I described above. It calls the speech-to-text from the audio to get the text and then it calls LUIS.

Comment: For CRIS I use different subscription key though, so your idea is that LUIS has the same features as CRIS, but they are somehow implemented inside this client?

Comment: The `CreateDataClientWithIntent` expects the two subscriptions keys, the one for CRIS and the one for LUIS as you can see at https://github.com/Azure-Samples/Cognitive-Speech-STT-Windows/blob/master/samples/SpeechRecognitionServiceExample/MainWindow.xaml.cs#L510. I'm not saying the they have the same features, I'm just saying that that method is likely a wrapper that is doing two calls to two different services.